# Can Matlab eliminate the path in URL and left only the domain part?

Tags: string, matlab, url, path, domain-name

Can Matlab eliminate the path in URL and leave only the domain part? Does Matlab have any function to eliminate the path behind?

Let's say, example 1:

```
 input  :http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/removing-noise-from-images.html
 output :http://www.mathworks.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) pattern should do the trick:

```
>> str = 'http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/removing-noise-from-images.html';
>> out = regexp(str,'\w*://[^/]*','match','once')
out = 
    'http://www.mathworks.com'
```

The search pattern `'\w*://[^/]*'` says look for a string that starts with some "word" characters (`'\w*`) corresponding to the protocol (e.g. http, https, rtsp), followed by the ubiquitous `://`, and then any number of characters that are not a forward slash (`[^/]*`).

**Edit:** The `'once'` option should eliminate a nested `cell`.

---

**UPDATE: just the hostname, allowing inputs with no protocol.**

```
>> str = {'http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/removing-noise-from-images.html';
          'https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi@dfvfv.html';
          'google.com/voice'}
>> out = regexp(str,'([^/]*)(?=/[^/])','match','once')
out = 
    'www.mathworks.com'
    'www.mathworks.com'
    'google.com'
```

---

**UPDATE 2: `regexp` madness!**

```
>> str = {'http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/removing-noise-from-images.html';
          'https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi@dfvfv.html';
          'google.com/voice';
          'http://monkey.org/';
          'stackoverflow.com/';
          'meta.stackoverflow.com'};
>> out = regexp(str,'.*?[^/](?=(/([^/]|$)|$))','match','once')
out = 
    'http://www.mathworks.com'
    'https://www.mathworks.com'
    'google.com'
    'http://monkey.org'
    'stackoverflow.com'
    'meta.stackoverflow.com'
```

---

```
% hostname.m
function hostnames = hostname(str)

hostnames = regexp(str,'.*?[^/](?=(/([^/]|$)|$))','match','once');
```

Comment: Try to make it general by including cases where 'http://' isn't there. It returns empty cell for that, as of now.

Comment: str = {'http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html',
       'https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi@dfvfv.html',
       'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101552/can-matlab-eliminate-the-path-in-url-and-left-only-the-domain-part'};
regexp(str,'\w*://[^/]*','match')

how do I put this in matlab editor with a lots of data instead of type in command window? I want all the output in matrix form [nx1]

Comment: now, I get the output like this with lots of data,
ans = 

    {1x1 cell}
    {1x1 cell}
    {1x1 cell}

Comment: @Divakar That's not a URL. Did the OP ask for that?

Comment: I want the answer with lots of data like shown as below:
ans = 

    'http://www.mathworks.com'
    'http://www.mathworks.com'
    'http://www.mathworks.com'

Comment: @chappjc, OP has mentioned links without the protocol names – ‘http://’, so I guess he needs a generic one.

Comment: @chappjc Can you try to make it keep the protocol names, that is 'http://', etc.?

Comment: @Divakar OK, I'll admit this update is a little nuts, but I think it covers all the bases, and keeps the protocol.

Comment: @user3340270 Inspired/peer-pressured by Divakar, I made an uber-regexp-expression that should handle all the cases.

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
function output_url = domain_name(input_url)

c1 = strfind(input_url,'//');
ind1 = strfind(input_url,'/');

if isempty(c1) && isempty(ind1) 
    output_url = input_url; % For case like - www.mathworks.com
    return;
end

if ~isempty(c1)
    if numel(ind1)>2
        output_url = input_url(1:ind1(3)-1); % For cases like - http://www.mathworks.com/ or http://www.mathworks.com/something/
    else
        output_url = input_url; % For case like - http://www.mathworks.com
    end
else
    output_url = input_url(1:ind1(1)-1); % For cases like - www.mathworks.com/ or www.mathworks.com/something/
end

return;
```

Example runs:

```
%% Long URLs with extensions
disp(domain_name('www.mathworks.com/help/images/removing-noise-from-images.html'))
disp(domain_name('http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/removing-noise-from-images.html'))

%% Short URLs without HTTP://
disp(domain_name('www.mathworks.com'))
disp(domain_name('www.mathworks.com/'))

%% Short URLs with HTTP://
disp(domain_name('http://www.mathworks.com'))
disp(domain_name('http://www.mathworks.com/'))
```

Return:

```
www.mathworks.com
http://www.mathworks.com
www.mathworks.com
www.mathworks.com
http://www.mathworks.com
http://www.mathworks.com
```

An alternative method and probably efficient one would be to use [REGEXP](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html), but apparently I prefer numbers.

**Edit 1:** If you prefer to use bunch of URLs at the sametime, you may use a cell array. Obviously, the output would be a cell  array too. Look at the following MATLAB script to get a feel of it -

```
% Input
in_urls_cell = [{'http://mathworks.com/'},{'mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html'},{'mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi@dfvfv.html'}];

% Get domain name
out_urls_cell = cell(size(in_urls_cell));
for count = 1:numel(in_urls_cell)
    out_urls_cell(count)={domain_name(cell2mat(in_urls_cell(count)))};
end

% Display only domain name
for count = 1:numel(out_urls_cell)
    disp(cell2mat(out_urls_cell(count)));
end
```

The above script returns -

```
http://mathworks.com
mathworks.com
mathworks.com
```

Comment: how about if I got a lots of data, and some of them domain end with '.my', '.com', '.uk'....?
can i process all of this in 1 time?

Comment: For example,
str1 = 'http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/removing-noise-from-images.html';
str2 = 'http://stackoverflow.uk/questions/22101552/can-matlab-eliminate-the-path-in-url-and-left-only-the-domain-part';
  str1(1:strfind(str1,'.com')+3)

how about the second string?

Comment: Edited for a general case.

Comment: why do I get the error like " disp(domain_name('www.mathworks.com/help/images/removing-noise-from-images.html'))
??? Undefined function or method 'domain_name' for input arguments of type 'char'.
"

I put the 'code' in 'matlab editor', 'example run's in 'command window', is there anything i do wrong?

Comment: Yes, you need to write the function as a separate file and add it to the current directory or add the path to MATLAB where the function file resides.

Comment: if I do not want to input my data at command window, I have a lots of data, so need to do at the matlab editor like B = {'http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html',
 'https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi@dfvfv.html'...};

then process all the output in array form

Comment: all of my code and data will be in matlab editor, then i just have to run then command window will process the output, without call out the file then input the data, can modify the code to this with the answer in array form?

Comment: Edited for your specialized requirements. Take a look.